# generating synthetic asset prices

Tags: stochastic-volatility, random-walk, geometric-brownian

I would like to use geometric brownian motion (gbm) in order to generate artificial asset prices. I know that gbm has constant volatility, therefore I somehow converted it to stochastic in a very crude way which result in something different than gbm. Other than gbm, is there any algorithm or method for such purpose?

thanks!

````
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
import pandas as pd
plt.close('all')




time = 10000
no_of_reps = 5
volatility_arr = np.zeros([no_of_reps,time+1])

for k in range(0,no_of_reps):
    
    
    delta_t = 1/time
    s0 = 1000
    asset_prices = [s0]
    gbm_np_array = []
    gbm_mean = 0
    gbm_std = 0
    volatility = abs(np.random.normal(0.5,1,time))
    
    for i in range(0,time):
        
        drift = 0.1*(-1+2*random())
        dw = np.random.normal(0,math.sqrt(delta_t))
        
        ds = drift*delta_t*asset_prices[i] + volatility[i]*asset_prices[i]*dw
        asset_prices.append(asset_prices[i] + ds)
    
    gbm_np_array = np.asarray(asset_prices)
    for i in range(0,len(gbm_np_array)):
        gbm_mean = np.mean(gbm_np_array[i:i+50])
        gbm_std = np.std(gbm_np_array[i:i+50])
        volatility_arr[k,i] = (gbm_std/gbm_mean)
    
    
    
    
    x = plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(asset_prices)),asset_prices)
    plt.show()
    
```
````

Comment: Have a look at how to simulate stock prices from the Heston (1993) stochastic volatility model. [This question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44957/numerical-simulation-of-heston-model) could be a start.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, however I am looking for a more general approach as it is not based on some theorem. I mean, in Heston's model there is a correlation which I would not look for. I am just looking for some implementation of volatility and drift as they are random at each iteration while generating a new price data point